# Is it possible to trigger different functions without duplicating code?

Tags: jquery

**FIRST:**

- Yes, I have searched google.
- Yes, I have searched this website (see attached image)
- I am not sure of what specific documentation to research, so I did
  not do that. But I am happy to do so if someone can tell me where I
  could have looked.

[image: None of these helped]
Now that is out of the way, here is my question. I have some code:

```
$('.button1').click(function() {
  $('.box').toggleClass('red');
});

$('.button2').click(function() {
  $('.box').toggleClass('black');
});

$('.button3').click(function() {
  $('.box').toggleClass('green');
});
```

Here is the [CodePen](https://codepen.io/kmarmet/pen/NjdmYm?editors=1010)

**Question:**
Is it possible to achieve the same goal without having a separate function for each button? I have been looking at selectors for awhile and I feel like that is the right path, but I'm not sure if they would help.

**Goal**
One total function, for the purposes of cleaning up my code...that will allow me to click any button but have a different action (say...apply a different CSS class). Possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibly solution would be adding additional information in your mark-up, for example using the `data`-attribute:

```js
$('.button').click(function() {
  $('.box').toggleClass($(this).data('color'));
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.box {
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: cornflowerblue;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin-top: 5vw;
}

button {
  border-radius: 2px;
  border: 0;
  background: cornflowerblue;
  font-size: 1.5vw;
  margin: 2vw;
  margin-top: 10vw;
}

.red {
  background: red;
}

.black {
  background: black;
}

.green {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box"></div>
<button class="button" data-color="red">Button 1</button>
<button class="button" data-color="black">Button 2</button>
<button class="button" data-color="green">Button 3</button>
```

Or extend your selector and set the color depending on the clicked button:

```js
$('.button1, .button2, .button3').click(function(e) {
  var color;

  switch ($(this).attr('class')) {
    case "button1":
      color = 'red';
      break;
    case "button2":
      color = 'black';
      break;
    case "button3":
      color = 'green';
      break;
  }

  $('.box').toggleClass(color);
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.box {
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: cornflowerblue;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin-top: 5vw;
}

button {
  border-radius: 2px;
  border: 0;
  background: cornflowerblue;
  font-size: 1.5vw;
  margin: 2vw;
  margin-top: 10vw;
}

.red {
  background: red;
}

.black {
  background: black;
}

.green {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box"></div>
<button class="button1">Button 1</button>
<button class="button2">Button 2</button>
<button class="button3">Button 3</button>
```

Comment: The `.toggleClass($(this).data('color'));` was exactly what I was missing. Two great answers! I also already have (for my actual project, not the codepen) data attributes included, so this should fit right in! Thank you!

Comment: I was already trying to write the `data` option is the first place. ;) So good option

Comment: This answer gives two solutions, while one of it is already in another answer. I would recommend to remove the duplicate to make it more clear for everyone.

Answer (score 2):

Add common class to all 3 buttons, Please see below code for reference

```
$('.btncommon').click(function() {
    switch($(this).attr('id')){
        case "btn1":
          $('.box').toggleClass('red');
            break;
        case "btn2":
          $('.box').toggleClass('black');
            break;
        case "btn3":
          $('.box').toggleClass('green');
            break;
    }
});
```

Comment: A switch statement! Nice. Very simple, thank you for this sir!

Comment: With this approach you should consider caching the `$('.box')` element. It could get expensive in case of performance

Comment: Yes, you are right empiric. use var box = $('.box') and use  box.toggleClass('green');

Answer (score 2):

And other option beside html attributes and `switch` is to use pure CSS

```
$('.btncommon').click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('something');
});
```

css:

```
.button1.something{
    background:red;
}
.button2.something{
    background:black;
}
.button3.something{
    background:green;
}
```

Personally I prefer this because it's faster than Javascript for the browser (but today maybe not that important) and less Javascript = less maintenance.

When I build components (which don't have a css file), I prefer the html attribute option.

Comment: I should have been more clear. The majority of what will need done is jQuery, not CSS. So if I was actually trying to just change colors (like my example) this would be perfect. But in my actual project I am trying to have one function and trigger different jQuery actions, if that makes sense.